# How i can i delete a selected item out of a listbox using php,javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I got 2 buttons. One is to add an item to the listbox. The other is to delete something out of the listbox. The filling happens with an array.
So what I need to know is: how can i delete a selected item out of the listbox?

Thanks
Stijn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function removeItem(selectbox)
{
var i;
for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
if(selectbox.options[i].selected)
selectbox.remove(i);
}
}
</script>

<SELECT id="item" NAME="item" MULTIPLE size=6 width=10></SELECT>
<input type=button onClick="removeItem(item)"; value='Remove Selected Item'>
```

Comment: I still got a problem: When I tried the code in a separate file it worked perfect. But when i tried to integrate it in my index.php it did not work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: found the solution a collegue of mine helped. Thanks for the help Sathsih

Answer (score 0):

You can delete one by one using this function.

```
<select id="list">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>

<button onclick="remove();">Remove</button>

<script>
function remove () 
{
   var list = document.getElementById('list');
   list[list.selectedIndex].remove();
}
</script>
```